flutter: ITMS-91053 cant see the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file
I did tried the declaring the api type and reason, and 'Target Membership' to my App. Then, ensure the file under either /iOS. BUT what I'm facing is, when I'm running 'pod install' in vscode, and view the pod generated in Xcode, the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file cant be visible. (Maybe this is the reason why I tried 2 attempt still facing api declare issue.)
Is it any step I'm doing wrong? Please point it out, Thx.
declare file as below:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>CA92.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>E174.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

I've been searching for this solution everywhere and tried, but the thing I facing is 'pod install' didnt see the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file.

pod install is nothing to do with privacy files.  It just installs dependencies. The privacy file needs to be in the application bundle after the build step

ok, so what should I do actually, to observe that the PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy is included in the runner after build?

@Paulw11 , I searched for some related to build step. Is it I need to modify the buildPhase of Runner to include the 'PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy' in it, and commit the ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file? I saw there's new added line relate to privacyInfo in it.

If the file is in your iOS folder and you have added it to the target in Xcode you are good to go.

Similar issues I'm also looking for, basically I created PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy from xcode. So after that I made some changes over there as per my app needs. Now when I'm generating the report, it's coming blank pdf. After publishing app same warning is coming. Is something I missed in the process?  I mean do I need to map that file somewhere else?

Issue solved on my side.
after adding the 'privacyInfo.xcprivacy' file in Xcode, check & make sure that the file under '/ios/Runner.xcodeproj' named 'project.pbxproj' updated:
under
 - /* Begin PBXBuildFile section */
 - /* Begin PBXFileReference section */
 - /* Begin PBXGroup section */

These section should have a new line added, related to PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file, commit this file with the changes. which uses to 'bring in' (copy) when the build phase. Anyone can provide additional info/ correct my misunderstanding. but so far, the issue solved for my app.
